# Make: error on libowfat program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, debian

Every time I try to use the make command on libowfat (a program) it seems to error.

Debian 7 Output:

```
root@testing1:~/libowfat# make
gcc -c byte/byte_chr.c -pipe -W -Wall -Wextra  -D_REENTRANT -O3 -fomit-leaf-frame-pointer  -I.
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fomit-leaf-frame-pointer’
make: *** [byte_chr.o] Error 1
```

I also tested on Ubuntu to make sure it's not the OS that's doing it.

Ubuntu 14.04 Output:

```
root@testing4:~/libowfat# make
gcc -c byte/byte_chr.c -pipe -W -Wall -Wextra  -D_REENTRANT -O3 -fomit-leaf-frame-pointer  -I.
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fomit-leaf-frame-pointer’
GNUmakefile:176: recipe for target 'byte_chr.o' failed
make: *** [byte_chr.o] Error 1
```

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Kind of sounds like "-fomit-leaf-frame-pointer" isn't a valid option for your version of GCC, doesn't it?  SUGGESTION: modify your Makefile and remove that option.  PS: You can do a `man gcc` from a command line and read about what `omit-leaf-frame-pointer` and `omit-frame-pointer` are supposed to do.

Comment: How did you configure the build?  Did you run a `./configure` script?  If it's a low-fat library, it may decide that `./configure` is too much like 'high-fat'.  In that case, you'll need to edit the makefile or whatever they do provide.  If it is configured, then there's a fault in the configuration process.  Deleting the `-fomit-leaf-frame-pointer` option isn't going to break anything. It presumably makes the code marginally slower, but I wouldn't worry about it.  The other option is to change the version of GCC to one that supports the option — I don't know if that's an upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: Make a copy of GNUmakefile.  Edit the original and put a `#` in front of the `-fomit-leaf-frame-pointer`.  On Mac OS X (10.11.3) I also ran into a problem with `fmt/fmt_escapecharxml.c:32:8: error: only weak aliases are supported in this configuration
 size_t fmt_escapecharhtml(char* dest,uint32_t ch) __attribute__((__alias__("fmt_escapecharxml")));` (fixed by adding `#if 0` and `#endif` around the function in `fmt/fmt_escapecharxml.c`, and then some slightly more complex issues that I've not resolved yet in other files.